# cstring string; vs char string;

Tags: c, char, cstring

what is the difference between

```
typedef struct node *node_ref;
typedef char *cstring;
struct node {
  cstring string;
  node_ref link;
};
```

and

```
typedef struct node *node_ref;
struct node {
  char string;
  node_ref link;
};
```

my program compiles fine with no warnings with either declaration, so I have no idea what difference it made.

Answer (score 4):

You've defined `cstring` as a `char *` so in the first case `string` is a pointer to a `char` and in the second case it's a single `char`.

Both valid code, but very different meanings.